# Resolving "no column name: " for string inputs in sqlite and python?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

Essentially, I am asking (1) What column the user wants to edit (UPDATE) and (2) What new value they want to update said column which. This is specified with WHERE id = x.

My problem is that, when updating the value for that column (say, updating "english" with "maths" for the "subject" column), it brings up the error:

sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: maths

At the moment, I print out a list of options for the user, from which they select what column they want to update. Note that, before this, they have specified what ID they want to edit, so no worries here. I've tried creating parameters and all, but my program will still fall back to "no column name: ". I suspect this is because sqlite cannot handle variables from Python, but I'm still stuck here.

```
print("[Which information would you like to edit?]")


edit_options = {1: "subject", 2: "education", 3: "years", 4: "nostu", 5: "fptime"}


edit_values = {1: get_one.subject, 2: get_one.education, 3:get_one.years, 4:get_one.nostu, 5:get_one.fptime}

while True:
    try:

        edit_number = int(input("\n>>> "))

        if edit_number < 1:
            print("Please enter a number between 1 and 5")

        elif edit_number > 5:
            print("Please enter a number between 1 and 5")

        else:
            break

    except:

        print("Please enter a number between 1 and 5")


edit_column = edit_options[edit_number]

edit_column_value = edit_values[edit_number]

print('''
Editing {0}
[Current Value]: {1} = {2}'''.format(get_one, edit_column, 
edit_column_value)) #get_one() is simply an instance from another class

edit_input = input("[New Value]: {0} = ".format(edit_column))


cur.execute("UPDATE teachers SET {0} = {1} WHERE id = {2}".format(edit_column, edit_input, index))

smdb.commit()

print("edit succesful")
```

Essentially, I want the user's input to update a certain column, where the previously entered ID is entered. Any help is greatly appreciated. I've noted that when entering INT values, this works - it just doesn't work with strings.

(Sorry if my code isn't highlighted, I don't know how!).

Comment: Why aren't you binding values to parameters in the query string? Don't build a string with values directly in it. Nothing good comes of that broken approach. http://bobby-tables.com/python etc.

Comment: *"no such column: maths"* There is no column with the name `'maths'` in your `teachers` table. [Edit] your Question and show the `CREATE teachers` statement

Comment: Yes, I think this is the problem, there is no column, and I do not want there to be a column

Comment: @user45411: *"I do not want there to be a column"*: Here: `teachers SET {0}` you format your SQL satement to: `teachers SET maths`! Did you consider to [edit] your Question and show the `CREATE teachers` statement?